# Intellisense error in razor view when create new module, after rename visual studio solution in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I use orchard source code and want rename solution for fast switching between different projects. But when I changed solution name, and created new module via Orchard.CodeGeneration module, my solution not reloaded and I must include new module to solution explicitly (RMC to Modules folder -> Add -> Existing Project...). When I added to module .chtml files, intellisense not working correctly (dont see html helplers or Model property, etc.). If I try compile, all worked good, without errors. 
If I rename solution back to "Orchard", and create module via codegen, intellisense working correctly for Razor view. 
My workbench: visual studion community edition 2015 update 3. 
Orchard version: 1.10.1
How i can fix this bug? Or is there another way to identify the project?

Comment: Renaming the solution isn't recommended as it is hardcoded in other places. I know it's annoying to have a million orchard.sln in your recent list, it annoys me too but be careful if you do this. Off the top of my head its expected to exist with some of the deployment scripts as well.

Comment: I second the comment of @rtpHarry. I tried once to rename my various orchard solutions but gave up after some time. It isn't worth the hassle in my opinion.